# Creating an object from an object and an array in Vue.js 2.0

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array and an object created using Vue.js, I could like to combine them into one 'selection' array in the format of:

```
selection[
{food: Chicken, quantity: 3},
{food: Rice, quantity: 2},
{food: Pasta, quantity: 1}
];
```

I have the following set up to be able to do it:

```
  var selection = []

  for (var i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
      selection.push({
          food: this.meals[i],
          quantity: creditsPerMeal[meals[i]]
      });
    },
```

As it stands I am getting a Syntax error but I am not convinced I should be doing this as part the data. I feel that I am pretty close.

Here is the full code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Credits carried through: {{ credits }}</div>
    <div v-for="meal in meals">
      {{meal}}
      <input :id="meal" :name="meal" v-model.number="creditsPerMeal[meal]" type="number">
    </div>
    <div>
      Credits used: {{creditsSum}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

    mounted() {
        console.log('Component ready.');

        console.log(JSON.parse(this.f));

    },

    props: ['f','c'],

    name: 'credits',
    data: function () {
     var meals = JSON.parse(this.f)

      var creditsPerMeal = {}
      for (var i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
        creditsPerMeal[meals[i]] = 0
      },

      var selection = []

      for (var i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
          selection.push({
              food: this.meals[i],
              quantity: creditsPerMeal[meals[i]]
          });
        },

      return {
        credits: this.c,
        meals,
        selection=,
        creditsPerMeal
      }
    },
    computed: {
      creditsSum () {
        return Object.values(this.creditsPerMeal).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

As you can see from the image below if I input creditsPerMeal updates but selection doesnt, how would I bind in a way that it would.

[image]

Edited computed

```
computed: {
  creditsSum () {
    return Object.values(this.creditsPerMeal).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  },

  createSelection: function (){
    for (var i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
       return createSelection.push({
          food: meals[i],
          quantity: creditsPerMeal[meals[i]]
      })
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you what is exact syntax error, I see few extra comma at end of for loop in your code: are they causing it, Can you create a fiddle of it?

Comment: Oh consider about cleaning your data model, this is very bad way, keep model of your app as much clean as it's possible, and it should contain only initial values and structure of your data.No loops there, no methods and other stuff - there are another objects in VueJS for that stuff.

Comment: Hello @Saurabh, I have fixed te Syntac error and creating the array however it isnt quite performing right. How would I make it so the object in the array automatically update with the input boxes? Using a watcher?

Comment: By doing than in a computed properly instwad of the data function

Comment: Thanks @LinusBorg I had tried adapting for computed property but returned... createSelection:"(error during evaluation)". I have added the code to the above could you see why there is an issue?

Comment: 1. `meals` is undefined 2. you can't return from inside the for loop. add the stuff to a variable and return that variable after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have indeed a syntax error in "selection=,":

```
return {
    credits: this.c,
    meals,
    selection=,
    creditsPerMeal
  }
```